# Can't find a way to use JSON.NET correctly

Tags: c#, json.net

Hi everyone i try to use JSON.NET with my json files. I want a collection of objects to iterate through and take the information i want.

Here's my json files
[EDIT FOR EXPLANATION] I have a collection of launchers (3 here but i will add more later with the same attributs). I need to be able to iterate through all of them and know if they are unlock or not. If they are unlock i'll need to take their attribut for some calcul.

```
{
  "Canon":{
    "Unlock": true,
    "FireRate": 0,
    "IsRotate": false,
    "RotateSpeed": 0,
    "NumberOfBullets": 0
  },
  "Rotator":{
    "Unlock": false,
    "FireRate": 0,
    "IsRotate": true,
    "RotateSpeed": 0,
    "NumberOfBullets": 0
  },
  "Back":{
    "Unlock": false,
    "FireRate": 0,
    "IsRotate": false,
    "RotateSpeed": 0,
    "NumberOfBullets": 0
  }
}
```

Here's my classes for mapping

```csharp
 [System.Serializable]
  public class Canon
    {
        public bool Unlock { get; set; }
        public int FireRate { get; set; }
        public bool IsRotate { get; set; }
        public int RotateSpeed { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfBullets { get; set; }
    }

 [System.Serializable]
    public class Rotator
    {
        public bool Unlock { get; set; }
        public int FireRate { get; set; }
        public bool IsRotate { get; set; }
        public int RotateSpeed { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfBullets { get; set; }
    }

 [System.Serializable]
    public class Back
    {
        public bool Unlock { get; set; }
        public int FireRate { get; set; }
        public bool IsRotate { get; set; }
        public int RotateSpeed { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfBullets { get; set; }
    }

 [System.Serializable]
    public class Launchers
    {
        public Canon Canon { get; set; }
        public Rotator Rotator { get; set; }
        public Back Back { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried to use JObject, JArray and so on but can't find the proper way to be able to do something like that (which, in this case, doesn't work at all :( ).

```csharp
    void Start()
    {
        List<Launchers> jsonList = ReadJson(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/BDD/Launchers.json");

        if(jsonList != null){
            foreach (var item in jsonList)
            {
                if(item.Unlock){
                   // Do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static List<Launchers> ReadJson(string pathToJsonFile){
        if(File.Exists(pathToJsonFile)){
            JObject myjsonfile = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(pathToJsonFile));
            List<Launchers> launcherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Launchers>>(myjsonfile .ToString());
            return launcherList;

        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the long post but if someone have some hints/solution, it would be greattly appreciate

Comment: Your Json represents a _single_ object, not a list

Comment: @stuartd so my json file is the problem ? I have write it wrong ?

Comment: Well we don't know whether you *want* to represent multiple `Launchers` instance or a single instance. But if you want to represent multiple launchers as a list, your JSON should use JSON array syntax: `[ element1, element2 ]` etc

Comment: @Rhend he is saying `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Launchers>(...)` instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Launchers>>(...)`

Comment: Separately, you could probably have a single class (which doesn't need the `Serializable` attribute btw) called `Launcher` with those 5 properties, then deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, Launcher>`. It depends on whether the names `Canon`, `Rotator` and `Back` are really fixed or whether they're just the names that happen to be present. (We really don't have much context here.)

Comment: If you add a `[` to the beginning of your JSON and a `]` to the end then you'd have a list of one item

Comment: I have edit my post with some explanation about how i will use my json.
@JonSkeet `Canon` `Rotator` and `Back` are fixed yes and they will not have the same value in each attributs. Also, i want to have one instance of `Launchers` with every launcher in it and make a loop through it.

Comment: You could still just have a single `Launcher` class though, and make the `Back`, `Rotator` and `Canon` properties of type `Launcher` in your `Launchers` class. (I'd recommend trying to find a better name than `Launchers`, if possible.) But if you want to iterate over all the launchers and don't really care much about the name, then a `Dictionary<string, Launcher>` might still be a simpler option.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right. I added a new property `name` and juste make a list of launchers. This looks better but now i need to change the way i deserialized my json. I have i `IList<Launcher>` so i need to figure out how to do this. 

Thanks !

Comment: @Rhend: You don't need to change the JSON - you could just deserialized the JSON that's in the question as a `Dictionary<string, Launcher>` - in each key/value pair, the key is the name. It means you don't get compile-time validation, but it keeps the JSON clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay thanks to @jonSkeet i have made some changes and now everything work as i want ! Here's what i have change to help someone with the same problem as me.

First of all a have change my json file to reflect what i really want (e.g. : A true list of launchers) :

```
{
    "Launchers": [{
            "Name": "Canon",
            "Unlock": true,
            "FireRate": 0,
            "IsRotate": false,
            "RotateSpeed": 0,
            "NumberOfBullets": 0
        },
        {
            "Name": "Rotator",
            "Unlock": false,
            "FireRate": 0,
            "IsRotate": true,
            "RotateSpeed": 0,
            "NumberOfBullets": 0
        },
        {
            "Name": "Back",
            "Unlock": false,
            "FireRate": 0,
            "IsRotate": false,
            "RotateSpeed": 0,
            "NumberOfBullets": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Then i have change my mapping to this :

```csharp
  public class Launcher
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Unlock { get; set; }
        public int FireRate { get; set; }
        public bool IsRotate { get; set; }
        public int RotateSpeed { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfBullets { get; set; }
    }

    public class Listlaunchers
    {
        public IList<Launcher> Launchers { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally my last bit of code to use this as i want :

```csharp
    void Start()
    {
        Listlaunchers jsonList = ReadJson(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/BDD/Launchers.json");

        if(jsonList != null){
            foreach (var item in jsonList.Launchers)
            {
                Debug.Log("LAUNCHER JSON => " + item.Name + " => " + item.Unlock);
            }
        }

    }

    static Listlaunchers ReadJson(string pathToJsonFile){
        if(File.Exists(pathToJsonFile)){
            JObject objectJson = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(pathToJsonFile));
            Listlaunchers launcherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Listlaunchers>(objectJson.ToString());
            return launcherList;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for helping me !